# Change opacity of span within a on div:hover

Tags: html, css

I would like to change the opacity of a `span` within an `a` when the `div` all of this is within is hovered.

HTML:

```
<div id="about">
  <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="/about"><h1>ABOUT ME</h1><br><span class="hover-text">test</span></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hover-text {
  opacity: 0;
}

#about:hover {
  change .hover-text opacity to 1
}
```

Is this possible to do with pure CSS?

Comment: Yes change your second rule to=>  #about:hover .hover-text { opacity:1}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it only works on child element.

**For example** .about class has child span then it will work

```
.about:hover .hover-text {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```css
.about{
  border:1px solid black;
}
.hover-text{
  opacity: 0;
  font-size:30px;
}
.about:hover .hover-text {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="about">
  <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="/about"><h1>ABOUT ME</h1><br><span class="hover-text">test</span></a>
</div>
CSS:
```

Comment: Late comment, but thank you! I previously didn't have a good understanding of how child elements work, but now I do!

Comment: glad to help you

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Its possible. Just use the correct selector

```css
.hover-text {
  opacity: 0;
}
#about:hover .hover-text {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="about">
  <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="#"><h1>ABOUT ME</h1><br><span class="hover-text">test</span></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.hover-text {
  opacity: 0;
}
#about a:hover .hover-text {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> it's invalid to place a block-level element like `h1` inside an inline element like `a`.

For fix your case, use this code:

```
#about:hover .hover-text {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```css
.hover-text {
  opacity: 0;
}

#about:hover .hover-text {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="about">
  <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="/about">
        <h1>ABOUT ME</h1>
        <br>
        <span class="hover-text">test</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#about:hover .hover-text{
  opacity: 1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.about:hover>.hover-text {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

'>' is used to apply css for that particular child class

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
#about:hover .hover-text{
   opacity: 1;
}
```

[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/mzmr/pen/gvwQjE)

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems a little confusing. From what I can tell, when you hover `#about`, you want to hide `.hover-text`

---

That can be done in pure CSS like so:

```
.hover-parent:hover .hover-text{
    opacity: 0;
}
```

This will work for more than just the about div (just make sure you add the `.hover-parent` class)